# Json nested objects deserialization

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I would like to dynamically create c# object based on the the consumed Json. I do not care about this json but simply would like pick out properties that I need.

I dont know if its best practice to use dynamic keyword and based on the created object I can create a whole new json structure.

How can I desearilize nested objects. Example json:

```
{
'name': 'James',
'Profile': {
    'body': {
        'id': 'Employee1',
        'type': 'Employee',
        'attributes': {
           props...

        },
        'job': {
          props..
        },
        'team': [],
    },
}
```

Here is a simple attempt.

```
        var test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);

        Console.WriteLine(test.ToString());
```

I can create object list however when I begin Parent/Child objects I cant seem to get it to work.

Below JSON works fine as an output:

```
'body': {
            'id': 'Employee1',
            'type': 'Employee',
            'attributes': {
               props...

            },
            'job': {
              props..
            },
            'team': [],
        }
```

Desired Output

```
    {
'name': 'James',
'Profile': {
    'body': {
        'id': 'Employee1',
        'type': 'Employee',
        'attributes': {
           props...

        },
        'job': {
          props..
        },
        'team': [],
    },
'Profile': {
    'body': {
        'id': 'Employee2',
        'type': 'Employee',
        'attributes': {
           props...

        },
        'job': {
          props..
        },
        'team': [],
    }
}
```

How can I deserialize nested objects?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Hi @SimpleCoderJames and welcome to StackOverflow! You can do something like this: `dynamic myNewObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);`

Comment: You've already deserialized the entire graph with `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json)`.

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar I would like to deseralize the nested json using the dynamic keyword without having to create strict object class

Comment: @SimpleCoderJames you already have. `test` contains the entire graph. If you want to treat it as a `dynamic` variable you need to use `dynamic test=...`. With `var test=` you got back a JObject that *still* contains the entire graph. You can treat it as a dictionary too, eg `test["name"].Value` will return `James`

Comment: @SimpleCoderJames, You already did it ! so what is your actual question?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos as suggested you have whole json as a object in your `test` variable

Comment: @SimpleCoderJames if that's the *actual* result of `test.ToString()`, you've stored something different in there, or deserialized a *different* string. Even that output shows nested objects in any case. Post the *actual* code you used to test deserialization.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: @SimpleCoderJames I suspect you have a *different* problem and assume it's caused by some problem in JSON.NET. Your own output though proves that nested objects work. You need to write and post a *minimal* program that exhibits the behavior you described, something that can be reproduced by others. I can easily post a two-liner that shows that deserialization works

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I understand but I have a structure where you have a rootobject that contains A parent object and within the parent component a list of child objects.

I get Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content: ,. Path '', line 21, position 13.' which is a valid json but does not recognise the nested objects

Comment: @SimpleCoderJames that's not what you posted in the question. This error complains about an invalid JSON string. Post the *actual* code, *actual* json file, or at least a sample that actually reproduces the exception

Answer (score 0):

You can use the json class with following this line of code

```
dynamic data = Json.Decode(json);
```

Comment: Where did `Json.Decode` come from? In any case the OP has already deserialized the JSON string

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JsonConvert`:

```
dynamic myNewObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
```

And then, you can access json properties like this:

`myNewObject.Profile.body.id`

Answer (score 0):

No repro. The string is already deserialized. `test` contains the entire graph. The expected output is produced as long as a valid JSON string is used :

This snippet :

```
var json=@"{
'name': 'James',
'Profile': {
    'body': {
        'id': 'Employee1',
        'type': 'Employee',
        'attributes': {
           'a':3
        },
        'job': {
           'a':3
        },
        'team': [],
    },
}";
var x=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(json);
Console.WriteLiine(x.ToString());
```

Produces :

```
{
  "name": "James",
  "Profile": {
    "body": {
      "id": "Employee1",
      "type": "Employee",
      "attributes": {
        "a": 3
      },
      "job": {
        "a": 3
      },
      "team": []
    }
  }
}
```

From the comments though, it looks like the *actual* JSON string isn't a valid JSON string and throws an exception :

> I get Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content: ,. Path '', line 21, position 13.'

This error points to the actual location in the JSON string that caused the problem. Perhaps there's an extra character there? Perhaps the text contains *multiple* JSON strings instead of one? The following string is *not* valid JSON - JSON *can't* have more than one root objects :

```
{ "a":"b"}
{ "c":"d"}
```

Logging tools, event processing and analytic software though store multiple JSON strings per file this way because it only needs an `append` operation, doesn't require parsing the entire text to produce results and makes partitioning easier. That's still invalid JSON though that has to be read and processed one line at a a time.

You many find this described as "streaming JSON", precisely because you can process the data in a streaming fashion. Instead of loading and parsing a 100MB event file, you can load and process a single line at a time eg:

```
IEnumerable<string> lines=File.ReadLines(pathToBigFile);
foreach(var line in lines)
{
    var myObject=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<someType>(line);
    //do something with that object
}
```

`File.ReadLines` returns an `IEnumerable<string>` that only loads a single line on each iteration. Instead of loading the entire 100MB file, only one line is loaded and parsed each time.